# Strange Google Chrome Float Bug - Fine in other browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float, html-email

I'm encountering a strange bug where I'm trying to float my table cells (that are block level and 100% width) and they end up side by side while the first cell behaves normally. You are specifically looking for the header.

**I'm using tables because this is an email.**

In other browsers they collapse just fine but on Chrome **desktop** and **mobile** they won't!

[image: Chrome float bug]

I've tried clearfixing the cells also...

http://jsfiddle.net/us600sos/ - jsfiddle display it just fine, even in Chrome. What is that about?!

http://news.yfish.co.uk/e/B3936E5E801047F09407600602EBA805/4/preview/ -
Here is the version you can test to see the error (Respond down)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Template</title>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
<style type="text/css">


    #outlook a { padding: 0; }
    .ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; } .ExternalClass { width:100%; }                
    .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div { line-height: 100%; }
    body, table, td, a { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
    table, td { mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
    img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    img { border: 0; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
    table { border-collapse: collapse!important; }
    body { height: 100%!important; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%!important; background-color: #ffffff; }
    a:visited { color: #414141; }

    @media screen {
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'humanst';
            src: url(humanist-521-bold.eot); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
            src: url(humanist-521-bold.woff) format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
                 url(humanist-521-bold.ttf) format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
                 url(humanist-521-bold.svg) format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
        }

    }

        .facebook, .twitter, .mail {
            display: block;
            border-radius: 100%;
            overflow: visible;
            -webkit-transition: all 1.2s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
            -moz-transition: all 1.2s ease; /* Firefox */
            -ms-transition: all 1.2s ease; /* IE 9 */
            -o-transition: all 1.2s ease; /* Opera */
            transition: all 1.2s ease;
            border: 2px solid #ffffff;
        }

        .facebook:hover {
            background-color: #718fcb;
            border: 2px solid #718fcb;
        }

        .twitter:hover {
            background-color: #61c4e4;
            border: 2px solid #61c4e4;
        }

        .mail:hover {
            background-color: #bfbfbf;
            border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
        }

          .full-width-cell {
      *zoom: 1;
    }

    .full-width-cell:before,
    .full-width-cell:after {
      display: table;
      line-height: 0;
      content: "";
    }

    .full-width-cell:after {
      clear: both;
    }

        /* Animated Fish */

        .swi {
            -webkit-animation: fishSwim 10s ease 4s infinite; 
            -moz-animation:    fishSwim 10s ease 4s infinite; 
            -o-animation:      fishSwim 10s ease 4s infinite; 
            animation:         fishSwim 10s ease 4s infinite;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes fishSwim {
          0%   { -webkit-transform: translatex(0);  }
          20%  { -webkit-transform: translatex(230px); }
          20.1%  { -webkit-transform: translatex(230px) scaleX(-1); }
          50%  { -webkit-transform: translatex(-180px) scaleX(-1);  }
          65%  { -webkit-transform: translatex(-270px) scaleX(-1); }
          65.1%  { -webkit-transform: translatex(-270px) scaleX(1); }
          100% {  -webkit-transform: translatex(0) scaleX(1); }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes fishSwim {
          0%   { -moz-transform: translatex(0);  }
          20%  { -moz-transform: translatex(230px); }
          20.1%  { -moz-transform: translatex(230px) scaleX(-1); }
          50%  { -moz-transform: translatex(-180px) scaleX(-1);  }
          65%  { -moz-transform: translatex(-270px) scaleX(-1); }
          65.1%  { -moz-transform: translatex(-270px) scaleX(1); }
          100% {  -moz-transform: translatex(0) scaleX(1); }
        }

        @-o-keyframes fishSwim {
          0%   { -o-transform: translatex(0);  }
          20%  { -o-transform: translatex(230px); }
          20.1%  { -o-transform: translatex(230px) scaleX(-1); }
          50%  { -o-transform: translatex(-180px) scaleX(-1);  }
          65%  { -o-transform: translatex(-270px) scaleX(-1); }
          65.1%  { -o-transform: translatex(-270px) scaleX(1); }
          100% {  -o-transform: translatex(0) scaleX(1); }
        }

        @keyframes fishSwim {
          0%   { transform: translatex(0);  }
          20%  { transform: translatex(230px); }
          20.1%  { transform: translatex(230px) scaleX(-1); }
          50%  { transform: translatex(-180px) scaleX(-1);  }
          65%  { transform: translatex(-270px) scaleX(-1); }
          65.1%  { transform: translatex(-270px) scaleX(1); }
          100% {  transform: translatex(0) scaleX(1); }
        }

        /* Icons Fade Down */

        .facebook, .twitter, .mail {
            -webkit-animation: fadeInDown 1.2s forwards;
            -moz-animation: fadeInDown 1.2s forwards;
            -o-animation: fadeInDown 1.2s forwards;
            animation: fadeInDown 1.2s forwards;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
            0% {opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);}
            40% {opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0);}
        }

        @-moz-keyframes fadeInDown {
            0% {opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);}
            40% {opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0);}
        }

        @-o-keyframes fadeInDown {
            0% {opacity: 0; -o-transform: translateY(-30px);}
            40% {opacity: 0;  -o-transform: translateY(-30px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; -o-transform: translateY(0);}
        }

        @keyframes fadeInDown {
            0% {opacity: 0; transform: translateY(-30px);}
            40% {opacity: 0; transform: translateY(-30px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0);}
        }

        /* Title Fade */

        .fade {
            -webkit-animation: fadeIn 2.5s ease forwards; 
            -moz-animation:    fadeIn 2.5s ease forwards; 
            -o-animation:      fadeIn 2.5s ease forwards; 
            animation:         fadeIn 2.5s ease forwards; 
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
          0%   { opacity: 0; visibility: visible; }
          50%   { opacity: 0; visibility: visible; }
          100 { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
          0%   { opacity: 0; visibility: visible; }
          50%   { opacity: 0; visibility: visible; }
          100 { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }
        }
        @-o-keyframes fadeIn {
          0%   { opacity: 0; visibility: visible; }
          50%   { opacity: 0; visibility: visible; }
          100 { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }
        }
        @keyframes fadeIn {
          0%   { opacity: 0; visibility: visible; }
          50%   { opacity: 0; visibility: visible; }
          100 { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }
        }

        /* Image fades */

        /* Left */

        .imgFadeInLeft {
            -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft 3s forwards;
            -moz-animation: fadeInLeft 3s forwards;
            -o-animation: fadeInLeft 3s forwards;
            animation: fadeInLeft 3s forwards;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
            0% {opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateX(-50px);}
            70% {opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateX(-50px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(0);}
        }

        @-moz-keyframes fadeInLeft {
            0% {opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateX(-50px);}
            70% {opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateX(-50px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateX(0);}
        }

        @-o-keyframes fadeInLeft {
            0% {opacity: 0; -o-transform: translateX(-50px);}
            70% {opacity: 0; -o-transform: translateX(-50px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; -o-transform: translateX(0);}
        }

        @keyframes fadeInLeft {
            0% {opacity: 0; transform: translateX(-50px);}
            70% {opacity: 0; transform: translateX(-50px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0);}
        }

        /* Down */

        .imgFadeInDown {
            -webkit-animation: imagefadeInDown 3s forwards;
            -moz-animation: imagefadeInDown 3s forwards;
            -o-animation: imagefadeInDown 3s forwards;
            animation: imagefadeInDown 3s forwards;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes imagefadeInDown {
            0% {opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);}
            70% {opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0);}
        }

        @-moz-keyframes imagefadeInDown {
            0% {opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(-50px);}
            70% {opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(-50px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0);}
        }

        @-o-keyframes imagefadeInDown {
            0% {opacity: 0; -o-transform: translateY(-50px);}
            70% {opacity: 0; -o-transform: translateY(-50px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; -o-transform: translateY(0);}
        }

        @keyframes imagefadeInDown {
            0% {opacity: 0; transform: translateY(-50px);}
            70% {opacity: 0; transform: translateY(-50px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0);}
        }

        /* Right */

        .imgFadeInRight {
            -webkit-animation: imagefadeInRight 3s forwards;
            -moz-animation: imagefadeRight 3s forwards;
            -o-animation: imagefadeInRight 3s forwards;
            animation: imagefadeInRight 3s forwards;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes imagefadeInRight {
            0% {opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);}
            70% {opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(0);}
        }

        @-moz-keyframes imagefadeInRight {
            0% {opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateX(50px);}
            70% {opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateX(50px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateX(0);}
        }

        @-o-keyframes imagefadeInRight {
            0% {opacity: 0; -o-transform: translateX(50px);}
            70% {opacity: 0; -o-transform: translateX(50px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; -o-transform: translateX(0);}
        }

        @keyframes imagefadeInRight {
            0% {opacity: 0; transform: translateX(50px);}
            70% {opacity: 0; transform: translateX(50px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0);}
        }

        /* Up */

        .imgFadeInUp {
            -webkit-animation: imagefadeInUp 3s forwards;
            -moz-animation: imagefadeInUp 3s forwards;
            -o-animation: imagefadeInUp 3s forwards;
            animation: imagefadeInUp 3s forwards;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes imagefadeInUp {
            0% {opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);}
            70% {opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(0);}
        }

        @-moz-keyframes imagefadeInUp {
            0% {opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(50px);}
            70% {opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(50px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateX(0);}
        }

        @-o-keyframes imagefadeInUp {
            0% {opacity: 0; -o-transform: translateY(50px);}
            70% {opacity: 0; -o-transform: translateY(50px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; -o-transform: translateX(0);}
        }

        @keyframes imagefadeInUp {
            0% {opacity: 0; transform: translateY(50px);}
            70% {opacity: 0; transform: translateY(50px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0);}
        }

        #zoom a {
            display: block;
            overflow: hidden!important;
        }

        #zoom img, .img-cell-one, .img-cell-two {
            -webkit-transition: all 2s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
            -moz-transition: all 2s ease; /* Firefox */
            -ms-transition: all 2s ease; /* IE 9 */
            -o-transition: all 2s ease; /* Opera */
            transition: all 2s ease;
        }

        #zoom img:hover {
             -webkit-transform: scale(1.07); /* Safari and Chrome */
            -moz-transform: scale(1.07); /* Firefox */
            -ms-transform: scale(1.07); /* IE 9 */
            -o-transform: scale(1.07); /* Opera */
             transform: scale(1.07);
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 740px), and screen (max-device-width: 740px) {

            body { width: auto!important; }
            table[class="full-width"] { display: block!important; width: 100%!important; }
            td[class="full-width-cell"] { display: block!important; width: 100%!important; float: left!important; padding: 0!important; text-align: center!important; }
            table[class="content-width"] { display: block!important; width: 96%!important; float: none!important; margin: 0 auto!important; }
            img[id="title"] { width: 100%!important; height: auto!important; }
            td[class="img-cell-one"] { width: 42%!important; float: left!important; display: block!important; }
            td[class="img-cell-two"] { width: 58%!important; float: left!important; display: block!important; }
            img[class="img-scale"] { width: 100%!important; height: auto!important; }
            img[class="think-tank"] { float: none!important; margin: 0 auto!important; }
            table[class="tagline-table"] { display: block!important; float: none!important; margin: 0 auto 20px auto!important; }
            td[id="view-padding"] { padding-top: 20px!important; padding-bottom: 20px!important; }
            table[class="social"] { display: block!important; margin: 0 auto!important; }
            div[class="center-header"] { width: 100%!important; max-width: 357px!important; margin: 0 auto!important; }
            td[id="featured-padding"] { padding: 0 20px 0 20px!important; }
            td[id="title-cell"] { padding: 0 20px 0 20px!important; }

            [class="mobile-hide"] { display: none!important; }

        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 520px), and screen (max-device-width: 520px) {

            td[class="gallery-split"] { display: block!important; width: 50%!important; float: left!important; }
            td[class="img-cell-one"] { width: 100%!important; float: left!important; display: block!important; }
            div[class="gallery"] { overflow: hidden!important; width: 100%; max-width: 480px; margin: 0 auto!important; }
            td[class="img-cell-two"] { width: 100%!important; clear: both!important; display: block!important; }
            div[class="gallery-bottom"] { width: 100%!important; float: right!important; }
            [class="block"] { display: block!important; width: 100%!important; }
            div[class="img-large"] { max-height: 150px; overflow: hidden; }
            td[id="gallery-clear"] { clear: both!important; }

            .img-cell-one, .img-cell-two {
                -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
                -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
                -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
                -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
                transition: all 1s ease;
            }
        }

</style>
</head>
<body bottommargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">

    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#fec10d" style="background-color: #fec10d;"><!-- wrapper -->
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#fec10d">

                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" class="full-width-cell">

                            <div class="center-header"><!-- ISSUE STARTS HERE-->
                            <table width="99%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" class="full-width"><!-- header -->
                                <tr class="block">
                                    <td height="25">&nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="block">
                                    <td width="33%" style="padding-left: 20px;" class="full-width-cell">

                                        <div class="clearfix">
                                        <table width="354" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" class="tagline-table">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <img src="think-tank.png" width="354" height="19" alt="THINK OUTSIDE THE TANK" border="0" style="display: block; border: 0;" class="img-scale">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        </div>

                                    </td>
                                    <td width="33%" align="center" class="full-width-cell">

                                        <div class="clearfix">
                                        <table width="68" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="http://www.yfish.co.uk/"><img src="logo.png" width="68" height="21" alt="Yellow Fish" border="0" style="display: block; border: 0;" class="logo"></a>
                                                </td>    
                                            </tr>        
                                        </table>
                                        </div>

                                    </td>
                                    <td width="33%" style="font-family: 'humanst', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 15px; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; padding-right: 20px;" valign="middle" class="full-width-cell" id="view-padding">
                                        <a href="[*Hosted*]" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">It's a crime, not to view online</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="block">
                                    <td height="25" colspan="3">&nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table><!-- end header -->
                            <div>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
              </table>

       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start by saying I love that you are using animation in an email. Looks brilliant! Hope you can at least get a few browsers showing it.

Now...
I don't see any need in the div around the header, without it the cells re-size just fine.
Remove floats, they won't work in email clients and aligns will work just fine in float's place for browsers.
It took me a while to work it out but you are missing your doctype. I also added the version of the charset definition I use.

I would suggest replacing the top of your email with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
```

Your cells are stacking fine now and everything is centered. I didn't have to change a lot but here is my version of your code in case you wanted to compare it to yours: http://jsfiddle.net/nivicious/xbmx3bwc/

Comment: Amazing, can't believe that's what was missing, a DOCTYPE!!!!
I thought it could be something like that as JSFIDDLE has i t's own meta data and it worked fine haha!
Thanks it is a cool email indeed - hopefully my audience open this up on their mobiles ;) - My animations work in most of the browsers :)

Comment: Great! Worded it wrong, I hope your animation shows up in some email clients, obviously it'll work in browsers lol